# Unit test failing with TypeError on res.cookie() for new access token

Tags: unit-testing, request, mocking, token, typeerror

We're aiming at testing the verifyAuth function to check whether it handles the case in which the AccessToken is not valid anymore while the refreshToken still is. The function is in javascript
Here verifyAuth

```
export const verifyAuth = (req, res, info) => {
    const { authType } = info;
    const cookie = req.cookies;
    if (!cookie.accessToken || !cookie.refreshToken) {
        return { authorized: false, cause: "Unauthorized, lack of info" };
    }

    try {
        const decodedRefreshToken = jwt.verify(cookie.refreshToken, process.env.ACCESS_KEY);
        const decodedAccessToken = jwt.verify(cookie.accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_KEY);

        if (!decodedAccessToken.username || !decodedAccessToken.email || !decodedAccessToken.role) {
            return { authorized: false, cause: "Token is missing information" };
        }

        if (!decodedRefreshToken.username || !decodedRefreshToken.email || !decodedRefreshToken.role) {
            return{ authorized: false, cause: "Token is missing information" };
        }

        if (decodedAccessToken.username !== decodedRefreshToken.username || decodedAccessToken.email !== decodedRefreshToken.email || decodedAccessToken.role !== decodedRefreshToken.role) {
            return { authorized: false, cause: "Mismatched users" };
        }
        switch (authType) {
            case "User":
                if (decodedAccessToken.username !== req.body.username && decodedRefreshToken.username !== req.body.username) {
                    return { authorized: false, cause: "Unauthorized user" };
                }
                break;
            case "Admin":
                if (decodedAccessToken.role !== "Admin" || decodedRefreshToken.role !== "Admin") {
                    return { authorized: false, cause: "Unauthorized admin" };
                }
                break;
            case "Simple":
                break;
            case "Group":
                if (req.body.members.email && (!req.body.members.email.includes(decodedAccessToken.email) || !req.body.members.email.includes(decodedRefreshToken.email))) {
                    return { authorized: false, cause: "Unauthorized group" };
                }
                break;
            default:
                return { authorized: false, cause: "Invalid authType" };
        }
        res.locals.message  = "Optional Message"
        return { authorized: true, cause: "Authorized" };
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
            try {
                const refreshToken = jwt.verify(cookie.refreshToken, process.env.ACCESS_KEY);
                const newAccessToken = jwt.sign({
                    username: refreshToken.username,
                    email: refreshToken.email,
                    role: refreshToken.role
                }, process.env.ACCESS_KEY);
                res.cookie(cookie.accessToken, newAccessToken, { httpOnly: true, path: '/api', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, sameSite: 'none', secure: true });
                res.locals.refreshedTokenMessage = 'Access token has been refreshed. Remember to copy the new one in the headers of subsequent calls';
                return { authorized: true, cause: "Authorized" };
            } catch (err) {
                if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
                    return { authorized: false, cause: "Perform login again" };
                } else {
                    return { authorized: false, cause: err.name };
                }
            }
        } else {
            return { authorized: false, cause: err.name };
        }
    }
};
```

the following line syxtematically throws a TypeError error despite the payload being on point
`res.cookie(cookie.accessToken, newAccessToken, { httpOnly: true, path: '/api', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, sameSite: 'none', secure: true });`

Coming here the unit test calling verifyAuth

```
jest.mock('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config();
it('should refresh access token if it has expired and return authorized', () => {
    jwt.sign.mockReturnValueOnce('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODU4NzM5OTgsImV4cCI6MTY4NTg3Mzk5OCwiYXVkIjoid3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoianJvY2tldEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJVc2VyIn0.QHvvCG5_yKTlA2BizT0NrtzHFPITaftkr5iNRxtZduk', process.env.ACCESS_KEY);
    jwt.sign.mockReturnValueOnce('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODU4NzAwMDQsImV4cCI6MTcxNzQwNjExMywiYXVkIjoid3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoianJvY2tldEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJVc2VyIn0.TvgzaTBcp6t6Kmk6ObRc3hSaX9nbGSbnDqFxVp2XmOI', process.env.ACCESS_KEY);
    
    jwt.verify.mockReturnValueOnce({username:'test',email:'test@test.com',role:'User'})
    jwt.verify.mockImplementationOnce(()=>{throw{name: 'TokenExpiredError'}})
    jwt.verify.mockReturnValueOnce({username:'test',email:'test@test.com',role:'User'})

    req.cookies.accessToken = jwt.sign()
    req.cookies.refreshToken = jwt.sign()

    jwt.sign.mockReturnValueOnce('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODU4ODYwNzEsImV4cCI6MTcxNzQzMjA4MSwiYXVkIjoid3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoianJvY2tldEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJVc2VyIn0.PAdv5Cv6CR3S4pYcjHUOgXXL5UkxC4pyKNZQl53z7WM',process.env.ACCESS_KEY)



    
    req.body = {username:'test',email:'test@test.com',role:'User'}
    res.locals = {refreshedTokenMessage: ''}
    
    
    const result = verifyAuth(req, res, info);
    expect(result).toEqual({ authorized: true, cause: 'Authorized' });
    
    
    expect(res.locals.refreshedTokenMessage).toBe('Access token has been refreshed. Remember to copy the new one in the headers of subsequent calls');
  });
```

the tokens are correct as you can check by yourselves on this website https://jwt.io/#debugger-io . Furthermore I'm not moking the function res.cookie() and process.env.ACCESS_KEY is read proprely

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong ?

I'm trying to set cookie.accessToken to NewAccessToken thanks to a res.cookie() but it's throwing TypeErrors for a reason I cannot comprehend